# DB2 - Archive mode - number of ARCHIVE logs larger than LOGPRIMARY

Tags: logging, db2, archive

maybe for someone this is begginner's questions.
I read lot of documentation and set:

```
LOGPRIMARY 6
LOGSECOND 4
LOGFILSIZ 4096
logarchmeth1 Disk - C:\archive
logpath C:\active
```

Number of logs in C:\active is 6 which is ok.
But current number of logs in C:\archive is 40.
How is that possible?
I thought that maximum number of primary logs in C:\archive will be 6 and then 4 LOGSECOND (if needed, they are not preallocated).

Allowed log space is breached but new logs are created constantly in C:\archive. How is that possible? 
I will be thankful if someone can explain me this.
On this way I do not see how can I get Transaction log full (except if I run out of total disk space) because new logs in C:\archive are created.

I am beginner so please sorry for simple question I did not find answer on Internet.
logarchmeth1 is the destination for archive logs I set them on 6 for PRIMARY how then I have 40 logs?
Thank you

Comment: Please do not ask the same question on multiple sites with different IDs (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59063/db2-archive-mode-large-number-of-logs-in-logarchmeth1-folder/59070#59070)

Comment: ok sorry I needed urgent answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable archive logging in a database, you're telling DB2 that you want to retain a copy of *all* transaction logs that have been created.  LOGPRIMARY and LOGSECOND only control how many active log files can be in use in the active log path at any given time.

Please read the documentation on [database logging](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006073.html) for more details.